# Setting QGIS user defined coordinate system (code problem)

Tags: coordinate-system

I'm trying to set custom CRS in QGIS v 2.16.3. (Serbia Gauss-Kruger Zone 7). I've got parameters from .prj file that I use when working with GlobalMapper:

```
PROJCS["Transverse_Mercator",GEOGCS["GCS_Geographic Coordinate System",DATUM["D_SRBIJA",SPHEROID["Bessel_1841",6377397.155,299.1528131060786]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9999],PARAMETER["central_meridian",21],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["false_easting",7500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["Meter",1]]
```

Can someone help me and translate this code into a form that uses the QGIS? This should be a modification of MGI 1901/Balkans zone 7:

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=21 +k=0.9999 +x_0=7500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=682,-203,480,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```

Comment: What happens if you just use [EPSG:31277](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/31277/) in QGIS? Does this work? Just asking because your .prj output looks almost like the MGI 1901/Balkans zone 7 (some strings are different)